# Similarity in "carry and sum" and "difference and borrow"

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra, adder

i know *carry and sum* from all the sources i studied in YT (particularly KNOWLEDGE GATE) except neso academy that teaches using *difference and borrow* in same place as *carry and sum*

Sources:-

[Knowledge Gate](https://youtu.be/8eJe9Sv8s70)

[Neso Academy](https://youtu.be/NO7Gt8IDSGA?list=PLW6Pvy5C5XKucfrqC32suPWZzEbXJeYLx)

What are the main difference between these two?
are they totally different or its just a different way to refer those.

Comment: In two's complement addition is the same as subtraction except for subtraction you invert all the bits of the second number and carry a 1 in,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Sum" is addition - when you add numbers using "manual" arithmetic, you may have to do a carry between columns.

"Difference" is subtraction - when doing subtraction in manual arithmetic you may have to borrow from the next column if the result would be negative.